# Counting words in JSON array mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, group-by, count

I need to count true and false words in a JSON datatype.
I have this JSON in the cell:

```
{"1": true, "2": false, "3": true}
```

The number of values may vary. I realize that I can count the total number of values in the array but how can I count true and false separately?
For total count I used `JSON_LENGTH()`

Comment: what's your DB's version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using below approach containing `JSON_LENGTH()`, `JSON_EXTRACT()` and  `JSON_SEARCH()` functions together even for the version `5.7` (`5.7.13+`) where an array(`js`) extracted in the subquery and they're splitted to individual array for each values (`true` and `false`) by using `JSON_SEARCH()` function containing `all` as the second argument, and then counted by `JSON_LENGTH()` function :

```
SELECT ID, 
       JSON_LENGTH( JSON_SEARCH(js, 'all', 'true') ) AS Cnt_True,
       JSON_LENGTH( JSON_SEARCH(js, 'all', 'false') ) AS Cnt_False
  FROM ( SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, '$.*') AS js
           FROM tab ) t
```

provided JSON field has quoted values such as `"true"` and `"false"`

`JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, '$.*')` still can be used in case that the boolean values are unquoted as in your case. But, this time some string operations would be needed. Here, I preferred using `CHAR_LENGTH()` function :

```
SELECT ID,  
       CHAR_LENGTH(js) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(js, 'true', SPACE(LENGTH('true')-1))) 
        AS Cnt_True,
       CHAR_LENGTH(js) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(js, 'false', SPACE(LENGTH('false')-1))) 
        AS Cnt_False        
  FROM
  ( SELECT *, JSON_EXTRACT(jsdata, '$.*') AS js
      FROM tab ) t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oyjhrqbsECEknrbLZGdXzo/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The database already contains a lot of records where there are no quotes for true and falsity. Is it possible to read the boolean values in an array? I tried using ``JSON_QUOTE`` but it doesn't works well...

Comment: you're welcome @SerhiyOsmolenko . I updated the answer due to the unquoted boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `json_table()`, availabe in MySQL 8.0.

You can first turn each json object to an array of values using path `$.*'`. Then, you can pass the resulting json array to `json_table()`, which will put each value on a separate row. The final step is conditional aggregation.

Assuming that the json column is called `js`, that would be:

```
select sum(x.val = 'true') cnt_true, sum(x.val = 'false') cnt_false
from mytable t
cross join json_table(js -> '$.*', '$[*]' columns (val varchar(5) path '$')) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d046062837e5a782c2bd68f2c2866e7)**

Sample data (I added another row to make this more meaningful):

```
| js                                 |
| :--------------------------------- |
| {"1": true, "2": false, "3": true} |
| {"bar": false, "foo": true}        |
```

Results:

```
cnt_true | cnt_false
-------: | --------:
       3 |         2
```

Comment: You count all json arrays in the column, and I need in the cell.

Comment: @SerhiyOsmolenko: what is the primary key of your table?